# How do I sign in to Deezer on a Lumia 800?

Tags: facebook, 7.x

I've got a Deezer app installed, but whenever I try to log in on a Lumia 800 (running 7.8) I get an error "Facebook account not recognised. Please try again". Their app just says login from a PC/Mac which works fine, so does anyone know if it is supported to sign in to the Deezer app on Windows Phone 7.x using a Facebook based account?

Comment: Can you test the same app on a WP8 device?

Comment: Works fine on Windows Phone 8.0, and also Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows Phone 7.x devices, (according to Deezer Customer Support), you cannot login with Facebook, but must use a Deezer account; to quote their support:

> To get a new password go to the Deezer home page on a computer and before signing in to your account click log in and make use of the "forgotten password" option.